# Is there a way to implement the Azure AD on-behalf-of (OBO) flow in NodeJS using a library like Passport?

Tags: azure-active-directory, passport-azure-ad

I've found examples on how to use passport-azure-ad to secure a WebAPI in NodeJS (e.g. using the BearerStrategy), but I haven't found any examples of implementing the OBO flow in NodeJS specifically.

In my situation, I have a client application that sends a bearer auth token to my NodeJS service in the Authorization header. If my understanding is correct, if I then want to have my NodeJS service call the MS Graph API as the user, I have to exchange the token for a different one as part of the OBO flow.

In the examples I've found for a service that uses .NET, there is a library for this purpose (and you call something like AcquireTokenAsync with the Bearer token as the assertion). Is there a similar library that should be used if the service is NodeJS instead of .NET?

I know it can be done by issuing [HTTP requests directly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow#service-to-service-access-token-request), I just didn't know if that was the preferred/only way to do it in NodeJS.

Thanks!

Comment: The below answer is correct and should be marked as such. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, adal-node package does not support on-behalf-of flow. To implement that we have to make a new HTTP call and pass assertion in the request. I would suggest you to read the incoming token in your service and make a new http call to (https://login.microsoftonline.com/b2bc09c8-9386-47b1-8aexxxxxxxxxx/oauth2/token) endpoint with assertion to get the token for MS Graph API.

Below is the screenshot to get the token in on-behalf-of flow using postman.

[image]

Below is the code to get the access token using on-behalf-of flow in node.js

var qs = require("querystring");

var http = require("https");

var options = { "method": "POST", "hostname": [ "login", "microsoftonline", "com" ], "path": [ "b2bc09c8-9386-47xxxxxxxx", "oauth2", "token" ], "headers": { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "cache-control": "no-cache", "Postman-Token": "739540c9-1e3d-4d74-bxxxxxxx" } };

var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
    var chunks = [];

```
res.on("data", function (chunk) {
    chunks.push(chunk);
});

res.on("end", function () {
    var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
    console.log(body.toString());
});
```

});

req.write(qs.stringify({
    grant_type: 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer',
    client_id: 'd1538209-a56f-4301-863dxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    resource: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/',
    client_secret: 'NITLQThsHDlPb0FR+8oXxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    scope: 'openid',
    assertion: 'incoming access token from native app',
    requested_token_use: 'on_behalf_of',
    undefined: undefined
}));
req.end();

You can extract the access token and use it against a resource in a bearer request.
I hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the details. I knew it could be done using http requests like this, it just seemed unusual that there wasn't a library for this, just becuase it seems like there is for other platforms.